# How to handle events for dynamically created objects in MFC?

Tags: c++, events, mfc

I am wondering how I can handle an event for a dynamically created variable, e.g. a list control.

```
CListCtrl* pList = new CListCtrl();<br/>
pList->Create(...);
```

How can I handle the event LVN_ITEMCHANGED for pList?

```
OnLvnItemchangedList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Do I have to create an extended CListCtrl or is there some other way? I would prefer not creating a extended class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LVN_ITEMCHANGED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is sent through WM_NOTIFY message from control to its parent so you just need to add LVN_ITEMCHANGE handler function in parent's class (e.g. CMyDlg):

In header file:

```
class CMyDlg : public CDialog
{
   ...
protected:
   afx_msg void OnLvnItemChanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
   ...
}
```

In source file:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDlg, CDialog)
   ...
   ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, IDC_LIST, &CMyDlg::OnLvnItemChanged)  
   ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

...

void CMyDlg::OnLvnItemchanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
   LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR); 
   *pResult = 0;
   ... // examine *pNMLV members for item's information
}
```

It does not matter how `CListCtrl` control is created (through resource editor or dynamically), approach is the same. Just make sure you are using correct control `ID` in `ON_NOTIFY` message map entry. (`ID` passed to `Create`/`CreateEx` or defined in Properties in resource editor).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Did not think of that I set the id with the call to create.